# maven-antrun-plugin skip target if any of two possible conditions holds

Tags: maven, ant, conditional-statements, maven-antrun-plugin

I can pass two properties A and B to maven via

```
 mvn test -DA=true
```

or

```
 mvn test -DB=true
```

If either A or B is defined i want a target to be skipped. I found it was possible when only A was considered like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>skiptThisConditionally</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          <target name="anytarget" unless="${A}">
             <echo message="This should be skipped if A or B holds" />
          </target>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Now B has to be considered too. Can this be done?

matthias

Answer (score 5):

I would do that with an external `build.xml` file allowing you to define multiple target combined with `antcall` and so using one additional dummy target, just to check the second condition.

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>skiptThisConditionally</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target name="anytarget">
                    <ant antfile="build.xml"/>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and the build.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project name="SkipIt" default="main">
       <target name="main" unless="${A}">
          <antcall target="secondTarget"></antcall>
       </target>
       <target name="secondTarget" unless="${B}">
          <echo>A is not true and B is not true</echo>
       </target>
     </project>
```

---

Alternative solution if you only have 2 conditions: using the `<skip>` configuration attribute for one condition (i.e. maven stuff) and the `unless` (i.e. ant stuff) for the other condition:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>skiptThisConditionally</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${A}</skip>
                <target name="anytarget" unless="${B}">
                    <echo>A is not true and B is not true</echo>
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```